# Can not load a pb model into a keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a pretrained pb model and I am trying to load it as a keras model so that I would run something like model.summary() but the type I have after loading the pb model is 'AutoTrackable' object thas has no attribute 'summary'. Here is the code I am using

```
model = tf.saved_model.load('my_model/') # folder that contains the pb model
model.summary()
```

and here is the error message:

```
"AttributeError: 'AutoTrackable' object has no attribute 'summary'"
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/34775) issue relate to your problem?